# Replace text with content from previous line

Tags: bash

I have a textfile that contains multiple blocks of the kind below.

I'd like to replace "replaceme" with the output from a tool, that takes "someword CODE1" as input (and "someotherword CODE2" etc).
I can place that output in a variable (or array if needed).
It should be done in bash.

Any suggestions?

```
Tag: CODE1 (1)
  *This: someword CODE1
    Some message that may contain all kinds of characters
       /path/to/file,143|25
replaceme
Tag: CODE2 (5)
  *That: someotherword CODE2
    Some other message that may contain all kinds of characters
       /path/to/anotherfile,110|30
replaceme
```

Comment: You are trying to replace 'replaceme' with 'Some message that may contain all kinds of characters'. Am I understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: You're basically asking us to write a script for you.  Perhaps you'll get lucky, but we are not a coding service; we don't generally work that way.  What *specific* problems are you facing in writing the script you want?  Narrow your question to focus on those.

Comment: What is the criteria for knowing which text to remember? Is it the line after "Tag:" or is it the text after "This:" or "That:"? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you had a looked at `awk` and its `system` function?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't asking for a complete script, though I'd be happy if someone did that for me :-)
More on the general angle of attack. I've tried various awk and sed commands, but I get stuck on sed substitution with commands.

For example, this works:

    `sed "s|foo|$(pwd)|g"`
but not
    `sed "s|foo|$(mycommand)|g"`